# event 4656 even though handle manipulation auditing is disabled

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, audit, eventviewer

1. windows server 2012R2
2. auditpol /set /subcategory:"Handle Manipulation" /Success:Disabled /Failure:Disabled
3. still getting events 4656 "A handle to an object was requested."

any ideas?

Comment: Is the server in an AD domain?

Comment: yes it's the dc

Comment: Do you have any Group Policy auditing settings that may taking precedence over your auditpol command?  Also, the command you typed in will not work. It's `disable`, not `disabled`... using the past tense of the word is a syntax error.

Comment: regarding the typo, i typed the text above from memory, didn't copy paste. wherein the server it's configured correctly.
as for the gpo settings everything seems fine.

Comment: ok there's some progress, i found that when i disable "Audit File System" then event 4656 disappears.
so the question is, should this event be generated by "Audit File System" setting???